# Python one class per module and packages

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to structure my app in Python. Coming back from C#/Java background, I like the approach of one class per file. I'd like my project tree to look like this:

```
[Service]
    [Database]
        DbClass1.py
        DbClass2.py
    [Model]
        DbModel1.py
        DbModel2.py
    TheService.py
[ServiceTests]
    [Database]
        DbClass1Tests.py
        DbClass2Tests.py
    [Model]
        DbModel1Tests.py
        DbModel2Tests.py
    TheServiceTests.py
```

1. Is the one class per file approach OK in Python?
2. Is it possible to create packages/modules in such a way so that packages work like Java's packages or .NET's namespaces, i.e. in DbModel1Tests.py:

   ```
   import Service.Model

   def test():
      m = DbModel1()
   ```

Comment: You may like to take a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, for 1: I don't see why not. I think, regardless of language this is a good idea as it provides you with a quick overview of what is to be found in a file when you know there will be only a single class in it. I would make a small exception for helper classes though, but as Python allows nested classes this can also be done quite nicely.

For 2: possible as well. In your example though, you simple load the module, thereby making its classes and functions available by the full namespace.

So, if you say `import Service.Model`, you can only access the class by using `m = Service.Model.DBModel1()`.

To import things into the current namespace, do a `from Service.Model import *` (or `from Service.Model import DBModel1` if you only need that class). Then you can do as you currently do: `m = DBModel1()`.

Comment: The end seems a little misleading - using the OP's structure, wouldn't one need to write `m = DBModel1.DBModel1()` after `from Service.Model import DBModel1`  (assuming class name is same as that of the .py file) ?

Answer (score 13):

Q1. You can use the 1 class per file style in Python, but this is unusual.

Q2. you'd have to use `from Service.Model import *` and do some stuff in `Service/Model/__init__.py` which is generally frowned upon. Avoid `import *` in Python

My personal advice on this: Python is *not* C#/Java. Trying to bend it to make it look like $other_language will cause frustration and poor user experience.

Keep in mind that:

- you can have other stuff than classes in Python modules (functions, for instance)
- you don't have to import a class from a module unless you need to instantiate that class. Especially, if your code only uses instances of DbModel1 which are passed as arguments to your functions / methods, there is no need for the import in that part of the code
- from `Service.Model.DbModel1 import DbModel1` looks bad. Prefer `from service.model import DbModel1` : avoid uppercase letters in file names and directory names, and group classes / functions logically in files (rather than grouping them in directories as you would do with the 1 class per file system.)

Comment: Why is having one class for file unusual in Python?

Comment: @Gewthen it is not mandated by the language, so it is not a common practise.

Comment: Regardless of whether I agree or disagree, this answer could be made more useful if some of the "do's and don't" have some explanation and reasoning behind them. Mentioning pep 8 would help on some of your points, but others need more (e.g. "generally frowned upon", "looks bad").

Answer (score 3):

You can have one class per module, but this is not required. I would say that it's more related to the length of each module (keeping them not too long is always a good idea).

Now, about your structure:

- you can declare your sub-folders as packages. For this, just create an `__init__.py` file in each sub-folder.
- once this is done, you can import the modules like this: `from Service.Model import DbModel` and use this as you wrote: `m = DbModel1.DbModel1Class()`

Notes:

- naming your files with first letter as uppercase is not really Pythonic (but class name should have it). This means that it should look like `service.model.dbModel1.DbModel1()`.
- you can do `from Service.Model import DbModel1` to directly import class from `DbModel1` module. This can be done through correct setting of `__init__.py` content (I don't know how to configure it exactly). [Some more informations here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Answer (score 0):

A python system is a set of modules, each module has a target, so you need use the most suitable approach to reach the target, it includes a class per module or a mix of functions and classes per module.